# Single skew along the bottom edge of an element

Tags: html, css

I have two images, one above the other. the image size for the to one is 100% x 350px, the bottom is not that important

It would just on the top image i want and the bottom edge to be skewed

i was wondering if this would be possible just using css and skewing the image and trying to keep the skew to 84 degrees.

thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, this is how far i am so far http://jsfiddle.net/aimlessboy/7vfq91Ld/

Comment: What i finding difficult is getting the height on the element the angle isn't two bad

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
image {
    -ms-transform: rotate(84deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(84deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(84deg);
}
```

Comment: hey Jack, thanks for the reply. sorry i don't think i had added my jsfiddle by the time you replied. the angle isn't the bit i am struggling with. it more keeping the height of the element.